# NGINX virtual subdirectory is serving PHP files as downloads

Tags: php, nginx

My server answers to the following virtual subdirectory paths:

```
www.domain.com/us
www.domain.com/ca
www.domain.com/fr-ca
www.domain.com/spa
```

Each of these is an alias for `www.domain.com`.

- If I attempt to access `www.domain.com/some/virtual/path`, it is correctly handed off to my `index.php` and processed by PHP-FPM.
- If I attempt to access `www.domain.com/us/some/virtual/path`, it is correctly handed off to my `index.php` and processed by PHP-FPM
- However, if I try to call `www.domain.com/us/file.php`, NGINX attempts to serve the file as a download. But without the virtual path, it is handled appropriately by PHP-FPM.

My virtual subdirectory paths are managed by this section in my NGINX config:

```
    ####
    # Catch virtual locations: /us, /ca, /fr-ca, /spa
    ####
    location ~ ^\/(?:(?<currentSite>us|ca|fr-ca|spa)(?:\/|$))(?<realPath>.*) {
        try_files /$realPath /$realPath/;
        break;
    }
```

.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       80;
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /certs/cert.key;

    root   ${LANDO_WEBROOT};
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ######
    # CloudFlare limit for headers is 8K - development should simulate this

    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

    ####
    # Catch virtual locations: /us, /ca, /fr-ca, /spa
    ####
    location ~ ^\/(?:(?<currentSite>us|ca|fr-ca|spa)(?:\/|$))(?<realPath>.*) {
        try_files /$realPath /$realPath/;
        break;
    }

    ####
    # Manage the REAL locations
    ####
    location /js {
        index index.html
        expires 100d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        break;
    }

    location /media {
        index index.html
        expires 100d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        break;
    }

    location /skin {
        index index.html
        expires 100d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        break;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Try to load the file if requested, if not found, rewrite to @missing
        # This should pass all requests through index.php

        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_param MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 500k; #Allow a greater amount of data to be included in cookies
        fastcgi_buffer_size 1000k;  #Allow a greater amount of data to be included in cookies

        fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `rewrite...last` to remove the language prefix from the URI, so that it can be processed correctly by the remaining locations in your configuration. In particular, `.php` URIs need to be processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(?:(?<currentSite>us|ca|fr-ca|spa)(?:/|$))(?<realPath>.*) {
    rewrite ^ /$realPath last;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
rewrite ^/(us|ca|fr-ca|spa)(?:/(.*))? /$1 last;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.